# Files are being uploaded with full write permissions

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, php

A CMS that I manage uses TinyMCE to allow users to write blogposts. TinyMCE has an image uploader. Recently, like in the last couple of months, the image uploader has started uploading images to our server and leaving them there with full write permissions.

Yesterday I discovered some malicious code that had been uploaded this way, and that led me to finding out about more files with bad permissions on several sites.

The developers at [Moxie Manager](http://www.moxiemanager.com/) (who created the uploader plugin), tell me that it runs in pure javascript and uses native PHP functions, and it will never do anything but inherit whatever permissions the PHP user (apache, in this case) has set.

So I'm wondering what could have caused files to start getting 777 permissions? The uploads file is 755, and images used to be uploaded with 644.

Server is apache, OS is Ubuntu. CMS is based on CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check /etc/apache2/envvars for umask
2. `grep -Ri 'umask('` through related php-files and check output.

Maybe some other options if you can give more information.